# Flink ConcatFileCompactor not working for Gzip File

Tags: apache-flink

I use Flink FileSink to write GZIP file to HDFS and want to compact small file.
I remember that GZIP file can be directly concatated together so I try to use ConcatFileCompactor but the final compacted file is corrupted and cannot be read as GZIP.

Why will this happen? Is it because the concat compacting serverice will miss some trailer in GZIP? Should I use RecordWiseFileCompactor instead but I think it will cost much more resources. I really want to know if I can make ConcatFileCompactor working.

The code is below:

```
FileSink<JsonNode> fileSink = FileSink.<JsonNode>forBulkFormat(
            new Path(hdfsUrl),
            new CompressWriterFactory<JsonNode>(new DefaultExtractor<>()).withHadoopCompression("GzipCodec")
    )
            .withBucketAssigner(new JsonNodeBucketAssigner())
            .enableCompact(FileCompactStrategy.Builder.newBuilder()
                    .setNumCompactThreads(hdfsCompactNumThread)
                    .setSizeThreshold(hdfsCompactThreshold)
                    .build(),
                    new ConcatFileCompactor())
            .build();
```

Updated:
I found the reason and create a JIRA ticket https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-32562

Comment: How did you validate that the resulting file is corrupt?

Comment: I cannot use `hdfs dfs -text` or `gzip -d` or `zcat` to read file content.